# GPU for Asus ROG Swift PG279Q (1440p)

Tags: graphics-cards, gaming, desktop, pc

I recently got a new monitor the [Asus ROG Swift PG279Q](https://www.asus.com/us/Monitors/ROG-SWIFT-PG279Q/): 1440p, 144hz, with g-sync.

I currently have i7-3770k, 32gb ram, with 2x GTX 670 powering it.

My question is what gpu would be a good fit for this monitor.  I am a little unclear on how g-sync effects the requirements.  Should I be trying to get my fps 120+?
I am getting ready to get a new gpu but I want to make sure I get one that does not leave me under-powered to take advantage of what my monitor offers.

I have been a fan of Geforce for a while and with the 1080/1070 it is a choice between to two unless there would be a big reason I should wait for a 1080ti.  From the benchmarks on YouTube of The Witcher 3, it seems people get around ~60fps at 1440p with everything maxed.  While Ultra is not necessary I would like to be able to do a mix of high/ultra level settings.

I am currently playing The Witcher 3: Blood and Wine and will be getting Dues EX: Mankind Divided when it is released, after those I will probably look into either Fall Out 4 or Rise of the Tomb Raider.

I would rather not spend $800+ on a gpu but if it will save me money a year later, I would rather buy 1 gpu then have to another for SLI 6-12 months later.

Comment: G-Sync means that the monitor will adapt to the GPU's frame-rate, so that you don't have to always get more than 144FPS for a good experience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have 2 x GTX 670 in SLI, getting a GTX 1070 will not yield much performance benefits. Running SLI is never as good as running a faster, more expensive single card so I would recommend you to get a GTX 1080 (should be enough for what you are doing) and SLI it later if for some reason it is not powerful enough.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Which brand/model do you prefer?

Comment: This is a very good recommendation. Not only is the GTX 1080 only $600 (avoiding the $800+), the performance benefit is staggering when compared to the GTX 670 SLI.

Comment: @Wozzie Really doesn't matter, buy from your own preference of colors/designs from reputable brands. If you are a big case with good airflow get a internal exhaust cooler (non reference coolers), if you have a small case then get an external exhaust cooler (NVidia reference cooler)